# How do I convert an array of ints to a NSString in Objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsstring, int

First off, I'm pretty new to coding so bear with me if this is a dumb question.
I don't know how to convert soemthing like int array[10] into a single NSString.
I've been searching for solutions, but so far, all i've seen is converting from an array to an string array.

First thing I tried was something like

```
NSString *String=[NSString stringWithFormat @"%i",array];
```

But the thing is, i know that I can do something like

```
NSString *String[NSString stringWithFormat @"%i%i%i...",array[0],array[1],array[2],.....];
```

But i'm trying to avoid that since I will be doing this for more than 10 variables and I will be doing it quite a bit with seperately named variables

Comment: You shouldn't have a C array of ints to start with. You should have an NSArray of NSNumbers.

Comment: @matt: I have some different idea. NSNumber should be used only with a purpose like coredata. Just for storing numbers you can go with int(NSInteger) and/or floats.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I totally agree, NSNumber should be thought of as a container format... for serialization and the like.

Comment: Uh I dont really understand why since i'm pretty new but i'll keep this in mind

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
int i[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

int len = sizeof(i) / sizeof(int);

NSMutableString * str = [NSMutableString string];
for (int j = 0; j<len; j++) {
    [str appendFormat:@"%i ", i[j]];
}
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

Comment: you should accept the answer if you are satisfies your need :)

Comment: Ah sorry, I've had an account to this site for a little bit just been a lurker so i dont really know what i'm doing :P