# Decimal to uint8_t array

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, der, tlv, asn.1

```
uint8_t certificateSerialNumber[] = {0x02, 0x04, 0x24,0xA8,0x16,0x34};
```

The decimal **614995508** (actual serial number)is converted to hexadecimal **24A81634**.

The above unit8 array is the representation on TLV(tag length value) triplet of serial number
where T is 0X02, L is 0X04 and V is the hexadecimal string.

So i'm able to split the hexadecimal string by two characters at a time

How to convert hexdecmial to TLV triplet format as shown above in unit8_t array in objective-c?
reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccertenroll/about-integer

Comment: What is "string/Integer"?

Comment: This reference might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635548/how-do-i-convert-an-array-of-ints-to-a-nsstring-in-objective-c/16635699

Comment: Change the type from 'uint8_t' to just plain 'int' and use the solution in the above reference; it should work.  Please post problem code if it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure your data is not encrypted?

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanq soo much for reply my array is ASN.1 representation

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @sbooth Thanq for viewing my question. Please find the edited question

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanq for viewing my question. Please find the edited question

Comment: @apodidae Thanq for viewing my question. Please find the edited question

Comment: Still unclear. Give example input and desired output. You are starting with the array `{0x02, 0x04, 0x24,0xA8,0x16,0x34}`? And you want to get what?

Comment: @matt in the array from index 2 to 5 is a hexadecimal value 24A81634 of 614995508.

Comment: I know that. Please answer the question I asked you. What actual result do you want to get?

Comment: @matt lets take another example

Decimal value :100000040509
Hex of above decimal: 174877863D

So we can divide hex decimal value to five parts [17 48 77 86 3D] 

when i  have given Decimal value it should convert to Hexdecimal value. 
that hexadecmial should convert into below uint8_t array format.
 

uint8_t certificateSerialNumber[] = {0x02, 0x05, 0x17,0x48,0x77,0x86,0x3D};

Comment: OK, so you are _not_ starting with the array? You are starting with a Decimal? And you want to _get_ the array? Is that right?

Comment: @matt yes when decimal is given as input it should convert to the unti8 array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm a little surprised at the Decimal, but whatever:

```
let what: Decimal = 614995508
var num = (what as NSDecimalNumber).uint64Value
var arr = [UInt8]()
while num > 0 {
    let rem = num % (16*16)
    arr.append(UInt8(rem))
    num = num / (16*16)
}
arr.append(UInt8(arr.count))
arr.append(2)
arr = arr.reversed()
arr.forEach {
    print(String($0, radix: 16), terminator: " ")
}
```

Result: `2 4 24 a8 16 34`

Comment: I have another query the hex conversion provided by you will support hex signed 2's compliment also?

Comment: Please do not say "thank you" in a comment. — Please do not introduce extraneous questions. I've answered the question you asked. If you have a different question, press the Ask Question button and ask it.